# Heat Autoscaling - Scaleup - Change a flavor

Tags: openstack, autoscaling, heat, ceilometer

I am using Heat Autoscaling in my environment. Can be able to see that it is working fine in case of scale up (Technically scale out) , that is adding a instance based on the load as well as deleting a instance is working fine as expected.

But I need to do scaling (Technically Scale Up) a resource once the load limit is reached.

That is Once the load limit which we mentioned is reached I need to scale the cpu resource that is changing the flavor of the instance.

Anyone please let me know how we can achieve it.

Any help is appreciable.

Heat yaml:

```
  web_server_scaleup_policy:
    type: OS::Heat::ScalingPolicy
    properties:
      adjustment_type: change_in_capacity
      auto_scaling_group_id: {get_resource: webserver}
      cooldown: 60
      scaling_adjustment: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Openstack HEAT Autoscaling feature, it is possible to scale in/out only the identical resource (of same flavor,image,..) dynamically based on the Ceilometer metrics. Your requirement is related to resizing an instance which has to be done manually and can't be done through HEAT autoscaling.